# Two queries in one php file, one is not working - why?

Tags: php, mysqli

In my code, there are two different queries. The first one is working - by which I mean it goes to the `if` path. The problem is with the second one which goes to the `else` path.

```
$adding_user_email=$arr[1];
$sessionuserid=$_SESSION['login_user_id'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "company";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}   

$sql = "INSERT INTO modes (userid,modename) VALUES ('$sessionuserid','".$arr[0]."')";
$sqlmodeid_uderid = "SELECT userid FROM register where useremail='".$arr[1]."'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$sqlmodeid_uderid = "SELECT userid FROM register where useremail='$adding_user_email'";
if ($conn->query($sqlmodeid_uderid) === TRUE) {
  echo "userid fetched successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sqlmodeid_uderid . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Help me out. (query is working fine)

Comment: Start by print_r'ing the variable you are trying to compare in the if statement to see what its value is.

Comment: which value you r asking me to compare ` $sqlmodeid_uderid ` or what.. please clarify...

Comment: Please look into [How to use connection](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp). It will help you.Check connection once at top as shown in link.

Comment: If you expect a variable to be true, but it is not according to the if block, you print_r the variable, to see its value, then figure out why it has that value. Your original question should not be 'why does it bypass my if statement', but why variable X has value Y.

Comment: Write `'{$sessionuserid}'` instead of `'$sessionuserid'` and change `"SELECT userid FROM register where useremail='".$arr[1]."'";` to `"SELECT userid FROM register where useremail='".$arr[1]."'\"";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition is a problem:

```
$conn->query($sqlmodeid_uderid) === TRUE
```

If we consult the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) for the `query` function we will see:

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

As you are dealing with a `SELECT` query, this call will never return `true`. It will return a `mysqli_result` object on success, and `false` on failure.

Instead you could rewrite this condition in a number of ways.

1. Check the query does not return `false`.

   ```
   if ($conn->query($sqlmodeid_uderid) !== FALSE) {
   ```
2. Use `==` instead of `===`. The first will cast between two different types (and the `mysqli_result` object will equate to `true` when casted to `bool`) whereas `===` performs a typesafe comparison, meaning the condition will only be satisfied if both operands are of the same type and have the same value.

   ```
   if ($conn->query($sqlmodeid_uderid) == TRUE) {
   ```
3. The same logic in point 2 can be wrote in a few different ways:

   ```
   if ($conn->query($sqlmodeid_uderid)) {

   if ((bool)$conn->query($sqlmodeid_uderid)) {
   ```

I would look at the php.net documentation on comparison operators for more info on this:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this...

```
$adding_user_email=$arr[1];
                    $sessionuserid=$_SESSION['login_user_id'];
                    $servername = "localhost";
                        $username = "root";
                        $password = "";
                        $dbname = "company";
                        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                        if ($conn->connect_error) {
                            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                        }   
                            $sql = "INSERT INTO modes (userid,modename) VALUES ('$sessionuserid','".$arr[0]."')";
                            $sqlmodeid_uderid = "SELECT userid FROM register where useremail='".$arr[1]."'";

                            $sqlmodeid_uderid = "SELECT userid FROM register where useremail='$adding_user_email'";
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second query, I think you should do like this instead of doing "=== TRUE"

```
$sqlmodeid_uderid = "SELECT userid FROM register where useremail='$adding_user_email'";

/* Select queries return a resultset */
if ($result = $conn->query($sqlmodeid_uderid)) {
  echo "userid fetched successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sqlmodeid_uderid . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Look at the examples in the doc : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php